# Best solution for preventing zoom on form field focus on ios or any other devices that do this on font-size 16px and under?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, input, zooming

Seems to me a lot of solutions from making the text 16px or using js to check if the phone is an iphone. Changing the style is not ideal and checking if it's an iphone seems a bit messy and over time more devices/browsers may have this behaviour.
Is there a simple rule that just prevents that default behaviour entirely no matter the device?

Answer (score 0):

You can disallow your website to scale. That is if your page is properly designed for phones though. Otherwise, I would not recommend using this solution.

To prevent your mobile page or form fields to float around add or set the following viewport in your `<head></head>` to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
```

Comment: I would still like the user to be able to scare though - I would just like to take away the auto scale when the form field is on focus - once the form has zoomed in it doesn't zoom back out